# Problem implementing a VGG11 from scratch in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a VGG11 from scratch on a dataset containing 16K images of 10 different species of animals. Even the training loss doesn't decrease in the first 10 epochs.

```
Epoch: 1, Training Loss: 2.2622, Validation Loss: 2.2299, accuracy = 0.2010
Epoch: 2, Training Loss: 2.2105, Validation Loss: 2.1941, accuracy = 0.2010
Epoch: 3, Training Loss: 2.1859, Validation Loss: 2.1793, accuracy = 0.2010
Epoch: 4, Training Loss: 2.1772, Validation Loss: 2.1757, accuracy = 0.2010
Epoch: 5, Training Loss: 2.1753, Validation Loss: 2.1749, accuracy = 0.2010
```

Here is the code for the network:

```
class myVGG11(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(myVGG11, self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2))
    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2))
    self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(), 
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2))
    self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2))
    self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2))
    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(0.5),
        nn.Linear(int(image_size/32)*int(image_size/32)*512, 4096),
        nn.ReLU())
    self.fc2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(0.5),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        nn.ReLU())
    self.fc3= nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(4096, 10))
    
def forward(self, x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = self.layer3(out)
    out = self.layer4(out)
    out = self.layer5(out)

    out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
    out = self.fc1(out)
    out = self.fc2(out)
    out = self.fc3(out)
    
    return out

vgg11 = myVGG11().to(device)
EPOCHS = 5
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0001
optimizer_vgg11 = optim.SGD(vgg11.parameters(),lr=LEARNING_RATE, weight_decay = WEIGHT_DECAY)
loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
train(vgg11, optimizer_vgg11,loss, train_dl,val_dl, epochs=EPOCHS, device = 'mps')
```

I also tried by downloading a VGG11 from torchvision,

```
VGG11 = models.vgg11()
VGG11.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, 10)
VGG11.to(device)
```

and then train it with the same training function. In this case everything seems to work. This makes me think the problem is in the implementation of  the myVGG11 class and not elsewhere in the code.

```
Epoch: 1, Training Loss: 2.1506, Validation Loss: 2.0727, accuracy = 0.2555
Epoch: 2, Training Loss: 1.9640, Validation Loss: 1.8940, accuracy = 0.3282
Epoch: 3, Training Loss: 1.7748, Validation Loss: 2.0457, accuracy = 0.2993
Epoch: 4, Training Loss: 1.6489, Validation Loss: 1.6886, accuracy = 0.4100
Epoch: 5, Training Loss: 1.5543, Validation Loss: 1.7528, accuracy = 0.4285

....


Epoch: 40, Training Loss: 0.1409, Validation Loss: nan, accuracy = 0.7625
```

Comment: Add `BatchNorm` layers. More recent VGG models has BatchNorm layers. Look for VGG models with `_BN` in their names in the [list of models in torchvision](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html#table-of-all-available-classification-weights)

Comment: You have `validation loss = nan` at the end of your training. This is usually not a good sign...

Comment: but models.vgg11() doesn't have BatchNorm layers. Why does it behave differently from the myVGG11? Shouldn't the two be more or less the same thing?

Comment: yes, I get lots of nan values as both training and validation loss between the 40th and 50th epochs. Should adding BatchNorm layers solve also this problem?

Comment: A model is not only the architecture - but the weights. You might have the same implementation as torchvision VGG11 of the _architecture, but you initialize the weights differently. What happens if you init your model with the same init as torchvision's VGG11's weights? Is there a chance you use a pretrained VGG11 when you load it from torchvision?

Comment: I don't think I loaded the pertained vgg11. If I load models.vgg11(weights=VGG11_Weights.DEFAULT), then yes, but in this case I get an accuracy over 0.9 from the first epoch

Comment: So, make sure your initialization method matches that of torchvision's VGG11.  Without `BatchNorm` training is very sensitive to the initial weights

Comment: I added batchnorm to my vgg11 and now it seems to converge. Thank you!